# Using Hibernate to get multiple rows into one object

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

I have the following table

```
Table T { Number: T_ID, String: Type, Number : AnotherKey}
```

The table has a composite primary key (ID and Type).

I need to load a class

```
class _T {
   Long T_ID;
   Map<String, Long> typeMap;
}
```

here typeMap is a map if all possible rows with the same T_ID

To give an example, 
consider rows

```
ID      Type      Another Key
01       'A'      100
01       'B'      101
02       'A'      100
02       'B'      103
```

This should load into 2 class instances

```
{01: {[A:100, B:101]}}, {02. {[A:100, B:103]}}
```

How to set this up in hibernate

Answer (score 3):

You could annotate `_T` class to achieve your goal as follows:

```
@Entity
public class _T implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5906661729869048121L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long T_ID;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="T",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="T_ID"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name="Type")
  @Column(name="AnotherKey")
  private Map<String, Long> typeMap;

  public Map<String, Long> getTypeMap() {
    return typeMap;
  }

  public void setTypeMap(Map<String, Long> typeMap) {
    this.typeMap = typeMap;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

You could just use `@ElementCollection` annotation but in that case your collection table `T` would have name `_T_typeMap`, join column would be called `_T_T_ID` and key column `typeMap_KEY` and value column - `typeMap`. Graphically it would look as follows:

```
Table _T_typeMap { Number: _T_T_ID, String: typeMap_KEY, Number : typeMap}
```

To achieve this:

```
Table T { Number: T_ID, String: Type, Number : AnotherKey}
```

you would add the following:

```
@CollectionTable(name="T",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="T_ID"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="Type")
@Column(name="AnotherKey")
```

Also, note that join column and key column are chosen as primary key of the collection table.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do with using a .hbm.xml configuration instead of annotations?